# Ant unzip task - how can I exclude the archive name from extracted hierarchy?

Tags: ant, unzip

How can I exclude the archive name from the file hierarchy after an ant unzip task?

For example, once ant's run the unzip task in the folder `C:\temp`, I want all the files from the archive archive, but instead I get `C:\temp\t\file.tmp`.

Can I effectively exclude the base directory inside the archive?

Comment: Your title is incorrect. Ant is not creating a directory based on the archive name. There is already a directory "t" inside the archive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a mapper specify how the files should look in the destination directory:

```
<unzip src="t.zip" dest="temp">
    <globmapper from="t/*" to="*"/>
</unzip>
```

Answer (score 3):

A better solution now is the [cutdirsmapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html):

```
<unzip src="t.zip" dest="temp">
    <cutdirsmapper dirs="1"/>
</unzip>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
<mapper type="flatten" />
```

See also https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ant-the-definitive/0596001843/ch04s10.html

> The flatten mapper removes all path information from filenames.

For example in build.xml:

```
<target name="extract-xsd">
    <unzip src="./cache/nl.packagename.example/xx/jars/somepackage.jar" dest="repository">
        <mapper type="flatten" />
        <patternset>
            <include name="**/Example.xsd"/>
            <include name="**/Example.wsdl"/>
        </patternset>
    </unzip>
</target>
```

As a result, the Example.xsd and Example.wsdl are put in the repository folder directly.